# How to properly declare arrays in mongoose schema?

Tags: mongoose

I wonder if there is a difference between the following ways of declaring an array in a mongoose Schema. Is one right? Are they different in any way?

```
authors: [{
    type: String
}]
```

vs.

```
authors: [{
    author: {
        type: String
    }
}]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, both are valid. But if you want to know the difference then let me show you how it actually differs

**Case 1:**

```
authors: [{
    type: String
}]
```

When you write like above in your schema, it means that authors key will contain array of string. To be more precise, document will be created like:

```
authors:[
    "Adam Freeman,
    "Kristina Chodorow",
    "Kyle Banker",
    "Eelco Plugge"
]
```

**Case 2:**

```
authors: [{
    author: {
        type: String
    }
}]
```

When you write like above in your schema, it means that authors may contain multiple objects having key as "author" and it will be of type string. To be more precise, document will be created like:

```
authors:[
    {
        author:"Adam Freeman"
    },
    {
        author:"Kristina Chodorow"
    },
    {
        author:"Kyle Banker"
    },
    {
       author:" Eelco Plugge"
    }
]
```

So, now it depends on how you want to design your database.